# ¿Cómo recuperar la hora (HH:MM) del timestamp guardado en Cloud Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, timestamp, google-cloud-firestore

Necesito representar la hora, que recupero de la data de un documento de firestore database.

He intentado de la siguiente manera:

```
renderMensaje: function(msj) {
    var date = new Date(msj.data().fecha*1000);
    // Hours part from the timestamp
    var hours = date.getHours();
    // Minutes part from the timestamp
    var minutes = "0" + date.getMinutes();
    var fecha = hours + ":" + minutes;
    // ...
},
```

Al imprimir date obtengo: "Wed Dec 31 1969 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (hora estándar central)". Lo cual lógicamente está mal.

Comment: Y que tienes en `msj.data().fecha` o directamente en `msj.data()`? quizas sobra el `*1000`

Comment: donde estas obteniendo el timestamp del servidor ?

Comment: @Txema , si muestro con: console.log(msj.data().fecha);
Obtengo: e {seconds: 1535000049, nanoseconds: 934000000}

Comment: no seria mejor guardar la fecha de cuando se guardo el documento como un hijo del archivo y de esa manera obtenerlo cuando llames al documento en Firebase, o podrias darme mas información para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar esto, bajo el supuesto que `msj.data().fecha` es un [timestamp de firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp):

```
renderMensaje: function(msj) {
    let date = msj.data().fecha.toDate() // convierte a un objeto Date de JS
    // Hours part from the timestamp
    let hours = date.getHours()
    // Minutes part from the timestamp
    let minutes = "0" + date.getMinutes()
    let fecha = hours + ":" + minutes
    return fecha

}
```